# How to verify length in javascript to be 0

Tags: javascript

I  want the following code to be executed ,what exactly should i put the value of token,
Does putting  `token ={}` makes the length as 0 or `token =''` ,can anyone explain?

```
  if (Object.keys(token).length == 0) {//api call to geneate token}
```

Comment: please add `token`.

Comment: What is problem you're facing with current code ? why not give it a try in console with the values you think

Comment: Both an empty object and an empty string will have zero keys.

Comment: Please explain your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Object.keys` is expecting an object, `token={}` is the right choice. This is called an "Object literal".

Answer (score 1):

The "length" property is only for array, string. OR, you can always define a "length" property for your objects (classes). In your case, you want to check "token" got any properties. The "Object.keys(token)" gives you an array of token properties. Then you use ".length" to check if it " === 0", means no properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
let token = {}; 
Object.keys(token).length;
```

This will return length as 0. As Object.keys() will return the array of keys of an object and .lenght will return the count of the array.